# In between jobs at the time of US tourist visa interview

Tags: visas, usa, tourist-visas, proof-of-employment

My wife is going to apply for **US B1/B2 (Tourist)** visa next month. On the day of her visa appointment (22 Nov 2023), she will be unemployed (in-between jobs) as the last day for her current employment is 10 Nov 2023. Her new job will start on 10 Dec 2023 - she has already signed the employment paperwork for her new job.

She has already filled out the DS-160 form by mentioning her present employer truthfully. However, at the time of the interview, the information about her "present employer" will no longer be accurate, since she will have left her job then. For such a case, does she need to update her DS-160, or will it be sufficient to explain this to the consular officer and keep her DS-160 unchanged?

- In the updated DS-160 (if required), should she keep the current employer section blank, or write the name of the new employer?
- Is there anything else that we could do on our side to provide proof of strong ties to the home country which would make it more likely that she gets her visa?

Basically, my question is what does "present" mean in DS-160? Is it "present at the time of filling out the DS-160" or "present at the time of the visa appointment"?

Comment: Ask the new employer if she can have an "on-boarding" day on Nov 13 to get login, security info, etc... May only take an hour, but then she can have a current employer :)

Comment: For the new employer, the (already signed) employment contract states the starting date as 10 Dec 2023. So I'm afraid the onboarding day won't be relevant (or even possible to change) since legally, she will start employment on the 10th.

Answer (score 3):

Present means exactly that, the [dictionary definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/present) is

> the period of time that is happening now, not the past or the future

With that cleared up, if she is filing while still employed:

-She must provide the most accurate information and fill in the name of the employer at that time. It is truthful and complete at the time of filing and can in no way be misconstrued as incorrect or misleading.

If, at the interview, she is asked what she does for work:

-She should again be truthful and mention that she is momentarily unemployed but has a job lined up for December. At this point it would be useful to provide some sort of proof of both the previous and upcoming employment (copy of the signed contracts etc).

Comment: She has already filled the DS-160 form. At the time of filling the form, she was (and even currently is) employed and has mentioned that truthfully. In a month when the interview takes place, she won't be employed. So, the information in DS-160 will be outdated then. She'll clear that up with the consular officer verbally during the interview and also mention her upcoming job (with proof).

Thank you for your input!